# Is it possible to mock ADFS?

Tags: java, saml, adfs

I need to integrate my java application with **ADFS SSO** with **SAML**. So I need a dummy (test environment), with **ADFS**.

Is there any way to mock **ADFS**, or buy test **ADFS**, I need just an **ADFS** response to work with it?

Also to create test environment I need to setup my application with https. So creation of the environment will take a lot of time, so is there any simple way to start developing java SSO integration?

Answer (score 2):

There's a free dummy SAML2 idp available at https://stubidp.sustainsys.com that can be used for testing.

*Disclaimer: The idp is mine, but since it's free and open source I don't make any money by referring users to it*.

Comment: Thanks Anders, could you explain more about how to use your SAML2 Idp...

Actully I have keyclaok and I created Identity provider using SAML 2.0 for my SP site and I want to test my keycloak Identity provider with ADFS IDP because client using it.

for more information what I did please see below link: 
https://www.keycloak.org/2017/03/how-to-setup-ms-ad-fs-30-as-brokered-identity-provider-in-keycloak.html

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a trial of Windows Server Enterprise? It is free for 180 days.

Don't try to emulate something for Quality Insurance purposes that you will use for real in Production.

So if you are looking for a cheap SAML2 IdP to validate SAML protocols cause you need to be compliant with all SAML IdP then @anders is correct, you can use his solution.

If your solution has thigher integration with ADFS, then my solution is better.

JF